# Copying the drawn contents of one UIView to another

Tags: cocoa, uiview, copy, cgcontext, quartz-2d

I'd like to take a UITextView and allow the user to enter text into it and then trigger a copy of the contents onto a quartz bitmap context.  Does anyone know how I can perform this copy action?  Should I override the drawRect method and call [super drawRect] and *then* take the resulting context and copy it?  If so, does anyone have any reference to sample code to copy from one context to another?

Update: from reading the link in the answer below, I put together this much to attempt to copy my UIView contents into a bitmap context, but something is still not right.  I get my contents mirrored across the X axis (i.e. upside down).  I tried using CGContextScaleCTM() but that seems to have no effect.

I've verified that the created UIImage from the first four lines do properly create a UIImage that isn't strangely rotated/flipped, so there is something I'm doing wrong with the later calls.

```
    // copy contents to bitmap context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mTextView.bounds.size);
    [mTextView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    

    [self setNeedsDisplay];

    // render the created image to the bitmap context
    CGImageRef cgImage = [image CGImage];

    CGContextScaleCTM(mContext, 1.0, -1.0); // doesn't seem to change result

    CGContextDrawImage(mContext, CGRectMake(
        mTextView.frame.origin.x,
        mTextView.frame.origin.y,
        [image size].width, [image size].height), cgImage);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I used to get a UIImage of UIView:

```
@implementation UIView (Sreenshot)

    - (UIImage *)screenshot{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

        /* iOS 7 */
        BOOL visible = !self.hidden && self.superview;
        CGFloat alpha = self.alpha;
        BOOL animating = self.layer.animationKeys != nil;
        BOOL success = YES;
        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)]){
            //only works when visible
            if (!animating && alpha == 1 && visible) {
                success = [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
            }else{
                self.alpha = 1;
                success = [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
                self.alpha = alpha;
            }
        }
        if(!success){ /* iOS 6 */
            self.alpha = 1;
            [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
            self.alpha = alpha;
        }

        UIImage* img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return img;
    }

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use in iOS 7 and later:

```
- (UIView *)snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:(BOOL)afterUpdates
```