# How can I duplicate the display of a UIView into another window?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, opengl-es, quartz-core

I have a need to display a letterboxed 1920x1080 UIView scaled to fit onto an iPad display in landscape. That UIView also needs to be displayed on an external display (HDTV) in full resolution. The UIView has many different subviews with user interactivity, animations, and even video.

I have this setup working right now, and it works for smaller animations, but if I need to move a large UIView across the screen, the animation slows down and drops frames. I am currently using the following method in a 2nd UIView on the other UIScreen.

```
[srcView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

Is there a faster way that I can get a mirrored view/layer/whatnot of that source 1920x1080 UIView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the [NDA sessions from WWDC 2013 concerning iOS 7](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/), some of the materials in Session 226, Implementing Engaging UI on iOS may be helpful. The relevant section starts at about 12:30 into the video, or slide 31 of the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you are asking for, but have you looked at using [Airplay Mirroring](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5209) with an AppleTV? It seems like that will provide the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: I need the view to display in full HD. Airplay mirroring only happens at 1024x768.

Comment: I CAN use AirPlay as a secondary, full-HD display though. But that means I've got to implement the mirroring in code, somehow.

Comment: Have you tried what is recommended here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365735/ios-iphone-is-it-possible-to-clone-uiview-and-have-it-draw-itself-to-two-uiviews?

Comment: If you have access to the [NDA sessions from WWDC concerning iOS 7](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/), some of the materials in Session 226, _Implementing Engaging UI on iOS_ may be helpful.